# C#: Html Form data on button onClick C# code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms

I want to send my `HTML Form Action` url to post by the C# pragmatically  not by the  `HTML` code on click of button action..

```
<form action="url" method=POST runat="server"></form>
```

What I am trying is

```
 <form id="form" method="POST" runat="server">
```

and in C# code

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm)this.FindControl("form");

      form.Attributes.Add("action", "url");

    }
```

This does not trigger the action method but url gets added.. how do i trigger call from C# code

Comment: You don't.  C# is a server-side language.  Form submission is a client-side event.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to change your form action, you can use "Server.Transfer" to post the form data to a different form:

```
Server.Transfer(url);
```

If you don't need to post the form data to the next form and just want to change to a separate URL, use "Response.Redirect" to redirect the browser to whichever page you intend:

```
Response.Redirect(url);
```

Comment: : System.ArgumentException: Invalid path for child request 'url. A virtual path is expected. this error i m getting on server.transfer

Comment: sorry i cant share but i have post my data to that url

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="THIS IS WHERE YOU PUT THE CODE">Send Info</button>
<p>This is the code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="alert('')">Send Info</button>
</p>
<p> If this code doesn't show, inspect it...

</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably want to add more to your answer explaining what you are doing with the code you have here.  Please edit your post rather than entering comments.